# Walkable area in SriteKit

Tags: sprite-kit

I want my player to move only on these platforms. How can I do it in SpriteKit?

I tries to use NavigationGraph, but no luck with it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, what I've done. I set a physicsBody for walkable objects to Alpha Mask, turned of gravity, set categoryBitMask to 1.

Then I check if a person clicked on one of my object, if yes, player moves there.

There was another problem with detecting if my physicBody was touched. To do that I've used this code

```
self.physicsWorld.enumerateBodies(at: touchLocation) {body,stop in

            if (body.categoryBitMask == 1)
            {
                print ("yes")
            }
        }
```